# How to SELECT post entries to which latest comment were created with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have tables `post` and `comment` that has foreign key(post_id) to post. I want to get 100 "bump ordered" post entries. The post entry to which latest comment entry was created comes first. My first attempt was:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM comment
    ORDER BY created_time DESC
    LIMIT 100
);
```

Returns:
`ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

The 2nd attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT post_id from
    (SELECT DISTINCT(post_id), posted FROM comment) AS c
    ORDER BY c.created_time DESC
    LIMIT 100
);
```

No error this time but doesn't do what I want. How can I make SQL do what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to select the 100 posts that have the most recent comments, you could use aggregation :

```
select p.id, p.title, p.author
from posts p
inner join comments c on c.post_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.title, p.author
order by max(c.created_at) desc
limit 100
```

With this technique, you need to enumerate all `posts` columns that you want to see in the resultset in the `select` clause *and* in the `group by` clause.

Another option is to pre-aggregate:

```
select p.*
from posts p
inner join (
    select post_id, max(created_at) max_created_at
    from comments 
    group by post_id 
    order by max(created_at) desc
    limit 100
) c on c.post_id = p.id
order by c.max_created_at desc
```

Comment: The first one works for me, but the second method did not. But one is good enough, thanks!

Comment: @RobertC.Holland: which problem do you get with the second query? An error, wrong results?

Comment: No error, just wrong results, the results looks like it gets sorted by post id 1 to max

Comment: @RobertC.Holland: ah yes I see, I left apart the `order by` in the second query. Fixed.